# iPhone user contact info

Tags: iphone, ios

If you look under Settings/Mail, Contacts, Calendar there is a setting for specifying your personal info (the 'My Info' setting). It basically lets you select an entry from your contacts list to use as your personal profile.

Does anyone know how this information can be accessed programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately, you cannot directly access the "My Info" contact information. You can allow the user to select his contact information from the Address Book, and you could look it up automatically later by saving the Record ID.

Here is the information Apple provides about the Address Book:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html