# Recovering contact info of the current user

Tags: ios, swift, contacts, contacts-framework

I'm having trouble searching online for this and I've missed it in the reference materials if it's there.

I'm writing an iOS app in Swift, and there are participants in the app whose contact info can currently be saved into the user's address book, using the Contacts Framework.

What I'd like to do is when the user has to save their own participant information into the system, I'd like to present their default contact info from the address book as the text fields' default text. I figured this would be possible using the contacts framework, but I'm not sure how to fetch the *current user's* information.

Does the contacts framework even keep track of that? I thought it did, because the Contacts app has my own phone number at the top of it's listings, but I realized afterwards that it's just the device's number, not a whole contact file. If so, do I search for it with a specific predicate or is their a function I can call?

Comment: As soon as I posted this, I found 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739724/iphone-user-contact-info' in the similar posts list...any chance this is out of date, or do I have to make user select from their own contacts still?

Comment: I'll look into this. Most contacts questions pre-iOS 9 are now out of date in favor of the new API.

Comment: @tktsubota thanks so much! I'm hoping this is available in the new framework, but I get why it might be left out as well.

Comment: Using predicates would be an option if there was some kind of "this user" token but I would have no way of knowing each user's name preemptively...

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I'm probably just going to have the user select from contacts as the other post recommends. I'm trying to get this in before a deadline.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure that my own contact data would come up just like any one else's, but I don't see how that's useful. When the user logs into my app for the first time with their iCloud credentials, I need to collect contact information (to share with other participants) and I was just trying to have intake fields preloaded so the user could click and move on to the app quickly...

Comment: I'm using cloud kit, and that has a token I can use as a unique identifier, but as far as I know there's no way to use that to harvest personal contact information...I'm pretty sure apple is trying to keep users info shielded from developers unless the user explicitly supplies it for security issues.

Comment: We should probably delete these comments, I am going to now, as the system keeps telling us to move this conversation to chat.