# Get the contact of the owner in react native Expo contacts

Tags: react-native, expo, contacts

I want to figure out how I can get the contact of the current user with expo contacts for iOS devices. In the iPhone contact book, my contact is indicated with a little "me" on the side. I want to figure out if I can identify this contact with expo contacts.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this async function:

```
const contacts = await Expo.Contacts.getContactsAsync({
  fields: [Expo.Contacts.PHONE_NUMBERS, Expo.Contacts.EMAILS],
  pageSize: 0,
  pageOffset: 0,
  sort: sortType
});
```

`sortType` can be what you want -  for example:

```
const sortType = Expo.Contacts.SortTypes.LastName
```

Comment: Maybe I was unclear, but that is not really what I meant. But I think what I was looking for isn't possible. - Still thanks!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739724/iphone-user-contact-info